# Virtualization Options with a non SLAT CPU

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I am working on a machine with an older intel CPU (core 2 duo 2.4 Ghz e6600) that doesn't have SLAT and doesn't support Hyper-V.

It is running Windows 8.1 (64 bit) with 4GBs of ram.  What software options do I have if I wanted to run a virtual machine, in this case, another instance of Windows (ex. Win 7)?

Am I SOL?  Will speed of VM be limited more by ram, cpu, or hard drive in this case?

Thanks,

Comment: This question seems to be offtopic and the would fit better at http://superuser.com/

Comment: No problem, feel free to come back here but with questions related to coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your best option is VirtualBox form oracle, i use it becouse i have the same tipe of procesor, an work really fine for me, the only think you can only instala x86 OS, but anything else works fine.

some spec's for your virtual machines

Windows 
Ram 1gb to 2gb, it is fine 
procesor one core only
HDD 40gb it almos enough for you want todo (as developer i only use it for testing)
video dont use it unless you need it

linux/unix
Console only
ram 256MB to 512MB
procesor one core only
HDD 40gb it almos enough for you want todo
video is not need here

GUI mode
ram 512MB to 1gb(i recomend use 2gb if your plan to use Ubuntu)
procesor one core only
HDD 40gb it almos enough for you want todo
video dont use it unless you need it

hope help you